# How to remove color from logs?

Tags: spring-boot, kibana, lombok, ansi-escape

When working with Kibana, severity is displayed incorrectly:

https://b.radikal.ru/b37/2007/98/5d373437d521.png

I'm trying to completely remove the color from the logs. I have these settings:

application.yml:

```
logging:
  level:
    root: INFO

spring:
  profiles: dev
  output:
    ansi:
      enabled: never
```

But still in the console there are colors in the logs:
https://b.radikal.ru/b25/2007/2c/f9c17ef402cb.png

Can I somehow prohibit the addition of color?

Comment: Do you have a log configuration file like spring-log4j2.xml or logback.xml?

Comment: No, no any configurations files.